# How do I find the gap between 2 dates in JSON file

Tags: python

How do I find the gap between 2 dates in JSON file `[{"start":"2004-09-8","end":"2005-7-5"}, {"start":"1999-9-7","end":"2000-5-3"}]`

```
[{"start":"2004-09-8","end":"2005-7-5"},{"gap":how many days gap"{"start":"1999-9-7","end":"2000-5-3"}]

import json
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
with open(r'/home/vijaya/Documents/task43.json','r') as list:
    data = json.load(list)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `datetime` and just check the `timedelta` like,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> data = [{'start': '2004-09-8', 'end': '2005-7-5'}, {'start': '1999-9-7', 'end': '2000-5-3'}]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for d in data:
...   start = datetime.datetime.strptime(d['start'], '%Y-%m-%d')
...   end = datetime.datetime.strptime(d['end'], '%Y-%m-%d')
...   d['gap'] = '{} days'.format((end-start).days)
... 
>>> data 
[{'start': '2004-09-8', 'end': '2005-7-5', 'gap': '300 days'}, {'start': '1999-9-7', 'end': '2000-5-3', 'gap': '239 days'}] # gap is in days
```

I really recommend you use [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) for datetime manipulation. It's a great module :)

As per the recent requirements, i have updated the code,

```
$ cat datediff.py
from datetime import datetime as dt

data = [ { "start":"2002-08-01", "end":"2004-09-12" }, { "start" :"1998-09-12", "end" : "2001-10-11" }, { "start":"1997-08-01", "end":"1998-01-12" }, { "start" :"1995-09-12", "end" : "1997-7-11" } ]

req_data = []
for first, second in zip(data, data[1:]):
    days = (dt.strptime(first['start'], '%Y-%m-%d') - dt.strptime(second['end'], '%Y-%m-%d')).days
    if days <= 0:
        days = (dt.strptime(second['start'], '%Y-%m-%d') - dt.strptime(first['end'], '%Y-%m-%d')).days
    req_data.append(first)
    req_data.append({'days': days})
req_data.append(second)

print(req_data)
```

Output:

```
$ python datediff.py
[{'start': '2002-08-01', 'end': '2004-09-12'}, {'days': 294}, {'start': '1998-09-12', 'end': '2001-10-11'}, {'days': 243}, {'start': '1997-08-01', 'end': '1998-01-12'}, {'days': 21}, {'start': '1995-09-12', 'end': '1997-7-11'}]
```

Comment: your code is super but,i did want  gap between single dictionary gap. i want gap between two dictionaries. 1 st dictionary start- second dictionary end then gap will be come

Comment: Okay, but only two dictionaries will be there or more ? If more, how do you decide between which ones to `diff` ?

Comment: data = [
    {
        "start":"2002-08-01",
        "end":"2004-09-12"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1998-09-12",
        "end" : "2001-10-11"
    },
    {
        "start":"1997-08-01",
        "end":"1998-01-12"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1995-09-12",
        "end" : "1997-10-11"
    }
]

Comment: data = [
    {
        "start":"2002-08-01",
        "end":"2004-09-12"
    },
    {
        "months":"how many months gap between (2002-08-01)-(2001-10-11) "
    },
    {
        "start" :"1998-09-12",
        "end" : "2001-10-11"
    },
    {
         "months": "how many months gap between (1998-09-12)-(1998-01-12)"
},
    {
        "start":"1997-08-01",
        "end":"1998-01-12"
    },
    {
        "months":"how many months gap between (1997-08-01)-(1997-10-11)"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1995-09-12",
        "end" : "1997-10-11"
    }
]

Comment: Okay, so it safe to assume the count of `dict` will be `even`? Because you need to compare between a pair. Also, that data structure doesn't make any sense. Where do you want the `'months'` key to be in ? A seperate `dict` with just `'months': <value>` ?

Comment: ha yes and last dictionary u will change to   {
        "start":"1997-08-01",
        "end":"1998-01-12"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1995-09-12",
        "end" : "1997-7-11"
    }

Comment: I am sorry, i am not able to follow. Why is it changed to ` { "start":"1997-08-01", "end":"1998-01-12" }, { "start" :"1995-09-12", "end" : "1997-7-11" }` ?

Comment: becuse difference od two date is -71 days so i will take to positive values

Comment: data = [
    {
        "start":"2002-08-01",
        "end":"2004-09-12"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1998-09-12",
        "end" : "2001-10-11"
    },
    {
        "start":"1997-08-01",
        "end":"1998-01-12"

    },
    {
        "start" :"1995-09-12",
        "end" : "1997-7-11"
    }
]

Comment: Okay, please paste the exact input and required output in correct format, in the question please

Comment: input                                                                                                                                data = [
    {
        "start":"2002-08-01",
        "end":"2004-09-12"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1998-09-12",
        "end" : "2001-10-11"
    },
    {
        "start":"1997-08-01",
        "end":"1998-01-12"

    },
    {
        "start" :"1995-09-12",
        "end" : "1997-7-11"
    }
]

Comment: Okay. And exact output in correct format ?

Comment: output                                                                                                                  data = [
    {
        "start":"2002-08-01",
        "end":"2004-09-12"
    },
    {
        "days":"294"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1998-09-12",
        "end" : "2001-10-11"
    },
    {
        "days":"243"
    },
    {
        "start":"1997-08-01",
        "end":"1998-01-12"

    },
    {
        "days": "21"
    },
    {
        "start" :"1995-09-12",
        "end" : "1997-7-11"
    }
]

Comment: I feel the output data structure is a bit weird, i have updated it as required nonethless

Comment: And, you should really clarify the question, the input, the output required, the reason for the logic(if ambiguous) used when asking a question :)

Comment: yes  i am clarified for input and output